# GParted is stuck on "shrink file system" (hfs+)

Tags: installation, mac, gparted, hfs+

I'm trying to install ubuntu 12.10 on am mac book pro 8.2 as a dual boot.

After disabling journaling on the mac hfs+ partition, I booted from the ubuntu mac cd and started gparted. There, I resized the hfs+ from 464 Gib to 346 Gib (second and third steps would be the creation of swap and ext4). After starting, it went through "calibrate /dev/sda2" in no time and skipped checking the filesystem (I had forgotten to install the hfsplus and hfstools package beforehand, that might be the reason).

Now, it has been stuck on the third step, "shrink file system", for 4.5 hours and it doesn't indicate any progress at all (the progress bar moves from left to right and then back again, and there is no time indicator). Is this normal behavior and should I just keep going, or did it run into some error and I just don't get any feedback?

Unfortunately, I post an image yet due to my reputation.

Comment: I'd say leave it a while. Depending on disk usage it may take rather long to shrink. Now that you started it you should **not force interrupt it** as this will lead to data loss.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hang in there. For me it took 14 hours to shrink 170GB to 110GB with 4GB of free space. I thought it might have been stuck too, but I was patient and it paid off.

If you use the [parted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Parted) command line tool to do the resizing instead of gparted, I believe it displays the progress. However if you've stumbled across this question then you're probably already in the middle of using gparted, so as Takkat said, don't interrupt it.

Comment: Yes, patience was the key. It was a little unnerving not seeing any progress, but in the end it worked out fine.

Comment: do `sudo iotop -o` in another terminal and you can see gpartedbin working, and it will disappear when its done.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is probably fixed in [gparted 0.23.0-1](http://gparted.org/news.php?item=191)

> preventing a user interface hang when resizing FAT16/32, HFS and HFS+ file systems.

As already said, if it happens to you **do not force interrupt it** and watch the progress with:

```
sudo iotop -o
```